# call method in embedded code with the help of BeanShell

Tags: java, beanshell

I need to call some java code in my code. I use BeanShell for it. 
So, I can do this:

```
public void testInterpreter() {
    Interpreter i = new Interpreter();
    i.eval("System.out.println("test1"));
}
```

But what if I want to call other method in interpreter? I want something like that:

```
public void testInterpreter() {
    Interpreter i = new Interpreter();
    i.eval("testMethod()");
}

public void testMethod() {
    System.out.println("test2")
}
```

But I'm getting an error "Command not found"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution.

I'm using `Janino Compiler` (http://unkrig.de/w/Janino)

```
String javaClass = "code of new java Class2 that extends existing Class1";
SimpleCompiler sc = new SimpleCompiler();
sc.cook(javaClass);
Class<?> executeClass = sc.getClassLoader().loadClass("Class2");

Class1 instance = (Class1) executeClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Now we have an instance of our Class2. Note that new Class2 should extend existing Class1 and we can call only methods declared in Class1.

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with the question in any way, shape or form.

Answer (score 0):

Set the instance of the class as a variable on the Interpreter:

```
    i.set("instance", this);
    i.eval("instance.testMethod()");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps you.

```
package beanshell;

import bsh.EvalError;
import bsh.Interpreter;

public class DemoExample {

    public static void main( String [] args ) throws EvalError  {
        Interpreter i = new bsh.Interpreter();
        String usrIp = "if(\"abc\".equals(\"abc\")){"
                + "demoExmp.printValue(\"Rohit\");"
                + "}";

        i.eval(""
                + "import beanshell.DemoExample;"
                + "DemoExample demoExmp = new beanshell.DemoExample();"
                + ""+usrIp);
    }

    public static void printValue(String strVal){
        System.out.println("Printing Value "+strVal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
package beanshell;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import bsh.EvalError;
import bsh.Interpreter;

public class Demo_Eval {
    public static Interpreter i = new Interpreter();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, EvalError, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
        String userInput = "printValue()";

        Object result = i.eval(""
                + "public class EvalUserInput extends beanshell.Demo_Eval{"
                + "public static void getUserInput(){"
                + userInput+";"
                + "}"
                + "}");

        Class<?> noparams[] = {};
        Class cls = (Class) result;
        Object obj = cls.newInstance();
        cls.getDeclaredMethod("getUserInput", noparams).invoke(obj, null);
    }

    public static void printValue(){
        System.out.println("Printed");
    }
}
```